# XAML Visual Studio 2017 cannot edit style anymore

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xaml-designer

I have Windows 10 Fall Creators Update on my PC. On Visual Studio 2017 and Blend, i can't anymore edit control's style anymore.

For exemple, i have a button in my page. I can create a style for the button by right click on it and chose option Edit Style > edit a copy... and when i create, it add style code but i can't edit it with XAML's designer.

And when i try to edit existing Style (by right click on the button option Edit Style > edit current element the option is grayed out.

[image]

anyone ever had the same problem?

EDIT 21/10/2017 : it seems that this problem comes from the designer XAML targeting the version Falls Creator Upate of Windows 10, in my projet properties, if i choose current app version Creators Update, it works but not when the project is on Fall Creators Update.

Answer (score 1):

You appear to have answered your own question, effectively. But for anyone else reading, the issue is the following.

In Visual Studio 2017 version 15.4, a major architectural update to the XAML Designer was introduced (which I'll call "New XAML Designer") alongside the older XAML Designer.  Visual Studio chooses a version of the XAML Designer based on the active project's target SDK: for anyone targetting Universal Windows Platform (UWP) 10.0.16299 or later (Fall Creators Update), the New XAML Designer will be used. Anything targetting an earlier UWP version, and anyone targetting Desktop .NET will get the old XAML Designer version.

Finally, the New XAML Designer is not yet feature-complete, and removed a set of existing features. One of the dropped features was "Edit Current Style."

So - the solution is to target an earlier SDK, at least for the purposes of accessing this one feature.

Links:

- [MSDN Blog: A Significant Update to the XAML Designer](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/09/11/a-significant-update-to-the-xaml-designer/)
- [Visual Studio 15.4 Release Notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.4#15.4)